# PostgreSQL 9.6 Cast text datetime to timetamptz different results

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

Why may I have different results of casting text datetime to timestamptz on my Postgres server?

[image]

The first date casts to `+03`, but the second one casts to `+04`. Why?

I have Postgres 9.6, my config:

```
datestyle = 'iso, mdy';
timezone = 'W-SU';
lc_time = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a daylight savings time change between these two dates, so that in your session time zone (determined by the current setting of the `timezone` parameter) a different UTC offset is used.

`W-SU` is an alias for `Europe/Moscow`, and Moscow changed from daylight savings time in the night from Oct 25 (Saturday) to Oct 26 (Sunday).